# French IIS7 Custom Error Pages Language

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

IIS7 provides custom error pages under;

C:\inetpub\custerr\en-US

However I'd like some other European languages too as by default only English is provided.
Has anyone seen an error page "language pack" for download anywhere. Do I have to install the full windows language pack, I'd rather not.

http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e9f6f200-cfaf-4516-8e96-e4d4750397ff

Tim.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that exists anywhere.  My advice would be to download the language packs to a computer you don't care about and copy them over manually.  I assume you're just trying to not pollute your server with unnecessary software.